# file://myserver/share/a/b/c in svn repository on linux

Tags: windows, linux, svn, samba, cifs

I have a Subversion repository on a windows cifs share. In the repository are same externals, now externals have to be absolute not relative, so whey point to file://server-name/share/a/b/c. Now when a working copy is checked-out to Gnu/Linux box it does not understand.

It there a way to map file://my-server/share to a directory?

Comment: you need to look into `mount` or better yet, set up `svnserve` or `http` to serve SVN. You really shuldnt use the `file://` protocol for anything but a one person local repo, you tend to run into issues down the line if you do. Voting to move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svn 1.5 and later actually support specifying externals by a relative path. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

- ../

Relative to the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals property is set

- ^/

Relative to the root of the repository in which the svn:externals property is versioned

- //

Relative to the scheme of the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals property is set

- /

Relative to the root URL of the server on which the svn:externals property is versioned